# How to extract specific keys for location to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multidimensional-array, key

I have a small data frame which looks like that:

```
place id,    geometry,
AXRT      {'location': {'lat': 51.112278, 'lng': 20.747889}}}}
```

[image]

I would like to arrive at something like that:
[image]

I have tried:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['geometry'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Geometry': np.array([subdct['x'] for subdct in df], dtype='datetime64[s]'),
                   'y': [subdct['y'] for subdct in df]})
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And cannot get through that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df = df[['place id']].join(df['location'].apply(pd.Series)['location'].apply(pd.Series))
print(df)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
  place id        lat        lng
0     AXRT  51.112278  20.747889
```

`SETUP`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'place id':['AXRT'], 'location':[{'location': {'lat': 51.112278, 'lng': 20.747889}}]})
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. This works, however I am wondering what if the setup would be slightly different e.g.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'place id':['AXRT'], 'geometry':[{'location': {'lat': 51.112278, 'lng': 20.747889}, 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 51.11367217989272, 'lng': 20.74911952989272}, 'southwest': {'lat': 51.11097252010727, 'lng': 20.74641987010727}}}]})

Comment: It seems that pandas does not recognize the "location" key. Is it normal?

Comment: For updated dataframe use `df = df[['place id']].join(df['geometry'].apply(pd.Series)['location'].apply(pd.Series))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply(pd.Series)` to expand the dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'place id': 'AXRT', 'geometry':{'location': {'lat': 51.112278, 'lng': 20.747889}}})
out = df[['place id']].merge(df['geometry'].apply(pd.Series), right_index=True, left_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  place id        lat        lng
0     AXRT  51.112278  20.747889
```